# How to use an already written SQL script in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm learning Entity Framework Core; I followed 2 or 3 tutorials where the instructors created the models from the beginning. Now I ran across this diagram (you'll find in the link below) and I wanted to use EF Core to create it.

Here are my questions:

- If I have a database already created in SQL Server, how can I use it in EF Core? I know only one way which is creating the models from zero to hero and add migration.
- If I need to create my models from zero to hero how can

Here are the SQL queries used to create the data tables: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-sample-database/

**EDIT:**

This article solved the problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first

Comment: You mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli ?